# How to merge two strings based on their matching prefix/suffix?

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to merge two strings based on their matching suffix/prefix. For example, given the two strings 'a' and 'b' below, I'm first using `Biostrings::pairwiseAlignement` to get their common suffix/prefix, which in this case is "cutie". I then need to merge the two strings. Concatenating would not be helpful because I would get repeats.

This is all I have for now:

```
a= "bahahahallocutie"
b = "cutiepalaohaha"
pairwiseAlignment(a, b, type = "overlap")
```

Which gives me:

```
Overlap PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [12] cutie
subject:  [1] cutie
score: 17.20587
```

What I want to get is the merging the two strings by the pattern that's the suffix of one and prefix of the other:

```
 "bahahahallocutiepalaohaha"
```

Comment: Please don't assume that everyone knows which package `pairwiseAlignment` is from. You should include a call to `library` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the pattern from the result of `pairwiseAlignment`. Then using `gsub` to remove the pattern from the strings you may use `paste0` to get the desired merged string. Note that in your final code you'll need to take account for the order of the original strings.

```
library(Biostrings)
pat <- pairwiseAlignment(a, b, type = "overlap")@pattern
paste0(gsub(pat, "", a), pat, gsub(pat, "", b))
# [1] "bahahahallocutiepalaohaha"
```